# Vue 2. How get child value throuth v-model binding

Tags: vue.js, custom-component, v-model

I'm using v-model in custom component, but when I try to get the data(value props) of the child component in the parent component, then I get the old value, although the data in the parent has changed. If I get the data of the child component through setTimeout, then I get the data I need. How do I synchronize the v-model @input event and the data I receive from the child element in the parent?

This is the logic: there are AppForm(parent) component and AppSelect(child) component. I'm binding v-model on AddSelect, and I follow the changes through watch() { v-model-data }. Then v-model data has changed I call AppForm.data() method, which iterates through the list of children and gets the value prop of AppSelect component, but this value is old.

Short example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wildflower-5seqx?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: There is an idea to use an additional method getValue() in AppSelect to get the actual value, but this is a crutch

Comment: The problem is not that the data in the parent component does not change, but that after a change in the parent component, the child component does not see these changes. Only after a period of time

Comment: Another component with <input> tag inside work fine.

Comment: I delete my false answer... I will keep an eyes on your question. I want the answer too. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the child component's prop inside a watcher watching the data property that the prop is bounded to. Of course, the watcher triggers *first*, then the data is passed onto the child component and the prop is updated. Its not a good design if you are relying on the order that Vue events and functions are fired, but if you must, you can use `vm.$nextTick()` function to get values after everything is synced.

```js
watch: {
    selectData(newV, oldV) {
      alert("Select data from parent component: " + newV);
      this.$refs.form.data();
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        alert("Show select data after 2sec");
        this.$refs.form.data();
      }, 2000);
    },
  },
```

Although, I'd suggest you shift the watcher inside the child component and access the `data` prop there.